# Size and position of child windows in QMdiArea

Tags: qt, resize, qt4, qt4.7, qmdiarea

I have `QMdiArea` object in `QMainWindow` which I did not have set with `setCentralWidget()` but as mentioned below.

```
MainWindow::createMdiArea() {
    QMdiArea mdiArea = new QMdiArea(this)
    mdiArea.setGeometry(0,0,1024,600);
    mdiArea.show(); 
}
```

I don't want to set this `QMdiArea` as the center widget. Now I am creating some child windows inside this `QMdiArea`, as following

```
MainWindow::createChildWindow()
{
     HelpWindow child1 = new HelpWindow(). // HelpWindow is a very simple class derived from QWidget and containing one QLineEdit. 
     mdiArea.addSubWindow(&child1);

     // Set the geometry of Child widget.
     child1.parentWidget()->setGeometry(0,0,400,100); // Setting geometry which I have saved.
     child1.show();
}
```

So far so good. But the problem is in the child window resize / close events I need to save the size of the `HelpWindow` and I am doing following to save the size of the child window in its resize / close events.

```
     saveHelpWindowSize(size());
     saveHelpWindowPos(pos());
```

Ok. Here comes the problem. The size I have got from the `size()` function inside the child window is different from the one which I have used in `setGeometry()` function, even I see it in some method other than resize event (i.e Close event).

So, Suppose first time the child window was created with the size (using setGeometry) 400, 200, when I go to close this window the size I will get from `HelpWindow::size()` might be say `(385, 190)` which I will save, and next time `setGeometry()` will get this size from settings, and at this time on close event I will get more smaller size, and eventually my child window will have size `(0, 0)`.

1: Any thoughts on how to sync both these sizes (i.e., the size if the child widget being set by `setGeometry()` function and the size of the widget I am getting from `size()` function of the widget)

2: Another question, I am receiving resizeEvent / closeEvent events etc in the child widget (`HelpWindow`) class, but I am not getting moveEvent when I move the child window inside `QMdiArea`, the only time I receive this event is when I maximize the child window inside `QMdiArea` (which I won't be doing). So I need to save the position of my child window when its position is changed. How can I do it?

Comment: Is this code compiling? First of all `QMdiArea mdiArea = new QMdiArea(this)` is wrong and even though you would say `mdiArea` is a pointer when it is getting out of scope you won't have access to the memory anymore(leak). These said, where is the declaration of `mdiArea` in `mdiArea.addSubWindow(&child1);`? I see a lot more issues with the code, please correct it, it is very confusing...

Comment: is this solved? I have similar question.